# access 2010 add new record to parent form without influence subform

Tags: forms, ms-access, subforms

I've got a parent form embedded with a subform. They are linked by ID.Lets say its form1(parent),form2(child) and ID.
I create a add new record button in form1 and it do bring me to a new form1.The problem is the 'acNewRec' also create a new record in the subform. When the form1.ID updated, the form2.ID is still '(new)'. I tried to add After Update Event to form1.ID and do requery to the subform, it just doesn't work. But when I jumped out and came back to look for the information. The record is there.

What I need is when the form1.ID updated, the subform will show the related information at once.

Can someone give any advice?

Comment: A new record in parent form should not automatically create a record in subform. Your button just moves subform to a blank form (with no saved data). To automatically add, you need to run an append query via a AfterUpdate/AfterInsert event or via a [data macro](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff973807%28v=office.14%29.aspx) trigger. Then, you can requery subform.

Comment: @Parfait, Thank you! I'll run an append query instead.